# Prestashop Custom Registration

Tags: prestashop

I am new to Prestashop. I have solid PHP experience. I would like to know how to add customer groups on customer registration page manually or how to add custom fields. I have tried to search ways to do it but I only see paid plugins.

Comment: In PrestaShop mostly everything is paid for, but with your solid PHP experience, you could make good use of https://devdocs.prestashop.com/ and develop exactly what you or your customer needs.

Comment: Adding custom fields to PS database is considered obsolete bad practice as it means adding overrides to PS core classes (which can cause lots of issues when upgrading modified table schemas, or when other module overrides the same classes as your own module). The proper way is creating a module, using hooks to synchronize your additional fields in your own tables.

Comment: Thanks I will try adding a module to do that

Answer (score 0):

There are good examples for this. Like "Login By Mobile" module.

They moslty use this hook: **AdditionalCustomerFormFields**.

If I had to do this, I would rather creating a new module, instead of editing the core files.

So this is an example module.
https://github.com/frederic-benoist/fbsample-extracustomerfield